# How to link multiple variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do a search box with auto fill, so it would redirect me to that page. As in, if I type "Au" it will show me Australia and will open that page. This is the problem. I have used [typehead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), but I just can't use links. I mean where should I put the links?

Please see the below code for reference:

```js
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];
    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Argentina', 'Armenia',
    'Australia', 'Austria', 'Vatican City', 'Venezuela', 'Vietnam', 'Yemen', 'Zambia',
    'Zimbabwe'];
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    name: 'states',
    source: substringMatcher(states)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twitter/typeahead.js/588440f6/dist/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="the-basics">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Type the name of the country">
</div>
```

Comment: The above code does not work! First build a autocomplete textbox properly

Comment: This works perfectly..add these lines:

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="typehead.js"></script>

You have to call these to make it work

Comment: What you will need to do is to add a click event which sends the text and on that even navigate to that page